# c# - ListBox + type item name to select it?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner learning c# and i am playing around with windows forms.

I am using Microsoft.visualbasic.Compatibility.FileListbox and i want to be able to type a name of an item to go to it. i.e select it.

I enabled "KeyPreview" on the form but this doesn't work for me.

can you please assist.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a bit of code to do that.
Just go to the ListBox's Events panel, double click on the KeyUp event and add your search code in the function that will be automatically generated.
Normally you will be searching over the items in the ListBox's Items collection.

Comment: Do you have an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand your question. Do you want to add an element to the list?
If so you can try this:

```
String name = "MyName"; 
listBox.Items.Add(name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I want to do is type the name of any item and navigate to it. don't know if I am making sense?

Comment: Let me see if i got it... You want to receive a name as an input and you want that name (if it exists) checked in a listBox? If so, you need to iterate over the listBox untill you find an item with the given value

Comment: Not Exactly, the input would be what the user types...so if there are two files that begin with "Si" and for example i type the word "Simple", it should select that item named "Simple"...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to select an item in a listBox based on a string you got as an input.
I would do something like this:

```
String name;

//Code....

for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
     if(name.Equals(listBox.Items[i].Text)){
        listbox.setSelected(i,true);
     }
 }
```